# Seaborn: How to plot multiple series to show their relation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe with this structure:

**df_values**

```
X     |  Y_A  | Y_B
10    |  100  | 110
11    |  200  | 220
```

I would like to plot a trend that focuses on the relationship between `Y_A` and `Y_B`, to verify visually follow a similar function.

Currently, by trying `sns.relplot(data=df_values)` I have the `X` values plotted as well (I don't necessarily need them plotted as a line), any tips on how Seaborn could be used with this dataset for he  purpose of showing the relationships between the trends? I am new to Seaborn so any ideas are very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just divide one by the other and use that as your `y`

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3,4],'Y_A':[100,200,300,400],'Y_B':[110,220,330,440]})
df['y_ratio'] =  df['Y_A'] / df['Y_B']
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='X',y='y_ratio');
```

[image]